# Prevent iPhones webkit from opening a new browser window (and thus exiting fullscreen) when clicking an `rel="external"` link

Tags: iphone, html, jquery-mobile, webkit

Opening my mobile webpage from my homescreen (after adding it to my homescreen), it starts in fullscreen mode, so far so good.

After logging in (form/submitbutton), the 'app' is still in fullscreen mode, which is also the desired result.

Now, when I click a link that has the `rel="external"` attribute, webkit opens a new window in Safari, so it exits the fullscreen 'app' I started from my homscreen, I would like it to stay in fullscreen mode.

`data-ajax="false"` has te same result. Removing `data-ajax="false"` and `rel="external"` will not exit fullscreen, but this way you can't link to a multi-page document (1 document with different `data-role="page"`).

Does anyone has the same problem, or even better, a solution?

I do not really care about the transitions, I just want the webpage to remain in fullscreen mode, (the user has to log in again when the new window has opened).

iPhone 3gs
M_webkit / 5.0.2

Comment: I solved it a different way. I removed the `rel="external"` from all the links. It will not exit full-screen mode (on iPhone) anymore, BUT this will not work in Firefox 3.6 (old yes I know, used for testing). In Firefox 3.6 the link in the address bar will get really messy, and clicking the back-button will therefor not work properly anymore.
Google Chrome 16.0.912.63 and Safari 5.1.1 and iPhone's 3gs webkit will not have this problem. I have not tested this on other (mobile) browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a script that pulls out the href and goes to the new url via javascript.

If you use jQuery it's as simple as:

```
$("a[rel='external']").bind("click",
    function() {
        if (this.href) {
            location.href = this.href;
            return false;
        }
});
```

Without jquery you'll need to use object detection and attach a click event to it with the same logic inside the anonymous function above.